# Smooth Movement in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, flappy-bird-clone

My Sprite jumps on the screen and looks laggy. I was wondering on how to make the movement smoother and not as laggy. The code I use for movement is below.

```
birdMovement = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(birdMoving) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
TunnelMovement = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.08 target:self selector:@selector(tunnelMoving) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [SKAction](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/moveTo%3aduration%3a) class instead of NSTimer.

Comment: would i just implement it the same way as i did with NSTimer?

Comment: @user2464778, something like this: [SKAction moveTo:CGMakePoint(100, 100) duration:2.0]. After creating an SKAction you can run this action on your sprite node like this: [node runAction:action]

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing your first game you should be using SpriteKit. It handles a lot of stuff like this for you. Be sure to read the documentation completely before beginning so you get an understanding of how it all works.

Comment: So would it not be possible to implement SKAction anymore, because instead of View it would have to be a Scene. Is there still a way of making the movement smooth?

Comment: Your best bet is to look into CADisplayLink if you don't want to use SpriteKit. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html